# purrr pmap in list-columns data frame

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, pmap

When I have a list-column data frame (df1) with two input columns (a and b), I can obtain a new column using map2

```
d1 <- mtcars %>% slice(1:10) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest(.key = "a")
d2 <- mtcars %>% slice(11:20) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest(.key = "b")
df1 <- d1 %>% left_join(d2) 

my_fun <- function(a, b) {
  # some manipulations that involve the dataframe a and b and result in 
  # another dataframe
  # below, just a trivial manipulation 
  a %>% bind_rows(b)  
}

df1 %>% mutate(z = map2(a, b, my_fun))
```

Let´s suppose now that I have a new data frame (df2) with 3 input columns (a, b and c).

```
d3 <- mtcars %>% slice(21:10) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% nest(.key = "c")
df2 <- d1 %>% left_join(d2) %>% left_join(d3)
```

How can I obtain a new column using the 3 input columns? As there is not map3, I guess I should be using pmap, but I don't know how.

Comment: `pmap(df[, 1:3], my_fun)`. Your function has to accept three or more arguments. Please try examples in the help page `?pmap`

Comment: Try `df2 %>% mutate(z = pmap(list(a, b, c), bind_rows))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Sathish commented `pmap` can be used and this can be used within `mutate` by placing the columns in a `list` and then apply the function

```
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>% 
   mutate(z = pmap(list(a, b, c), bind_rows))
```

Comment: missed you the whole day :D <3

Comment: @AndreElrico  ha ha